# SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend not works

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm trying to send message to subscribed user with spring-starter-websocket, but it looks like convertAndSend simply doesn't send message. @SendTo works. 
**My config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

private final HttpHandshakeInterceptor httpHandshakeInterceptor;

public WebSocketConfig(HttpHandshakeInterceptor httpHandshakeInterceptor) {
    this.httpHandshakeInterceptor = httpHandshakeInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setInterceptors(httpHandshakeInterceptor);
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/notifications");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class NotificationController {

    private final NotificationService notificationService;
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public NotificationController(NotificationService notificationService, SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/echo")
    public void send(String text) {
        template.convertAndSend("/notifications", text);
    }
}
```

**Test Case:**

```
@Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService;

    @Test
    public void testSubscribe() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        StompSession stompSession = stompClient.connect(WEBSOCKET_URI, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(httpHeaders),
                new StompSessionHandlerAdapter(){}).get();

        stompSession.subscribe(WEBSOCKET_TOPIC, new DefaultStompFrameHandler());

        stompSession.send("/app/echo", "Test".getBytes());
        Assert.assertEquals("Test", blockingQueue.poll(1, SECONDS));
    }

    class DefaultStompFrameHandler implements StompFrameHandler {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            return byte[].class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
            blockingQueue.offer(new String((byte[]) o));
        }
    }
```

As result, i have emзty queue. @SentTo works perfect.

UPD: convertAndSend works, but only from controller.

P.S. Sorry for my English, hope you understood problem :-)

Comment: I have the same problem. I inject `SimpMessagingTemplate` into my other classes and it won't send. Through the `@Controller` class it works. Did you find a solution, or the problem?

Comment: Nope. I'll post solution here when i'll find it.